# XMLHttpRequest for XSS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xss

Is it able to do cross-site scripting using a XMLHttpRequest as post?
For example if I have a chat where people write.

You normally won't be able to do scripts like: `<script>alert("test")</script>`.
But however you will be able to write a normal message for example "Hey!".
That is because the website filters the `<script>` tags.

But what if I bypass the filter by sending a XMLHttpRequest so the post data will be sent directly to the server and not through any security checks. Will I be able to use the script tags and execute a script?

I can provide a visual explaination in pictures if requested.
Thanks and stay awesome! Glad for any answers.

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is one of the security measures that would prevent this from happening. Also [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: It sounds like your chat application trusts the client to filter out any bad messages which is never good. Your security layer must be on the server, there is no way around that, though it might also exist in the client to make the user experience better (ie not sending messages to the server if you know they'll be rejected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the XMLHttpRequest is processed by server, XSS filtering can be implemented

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, what content-type should I use for my requestHeader? Right now I have: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: You can use application/json if it is in JSON format. If purely plain text, you can use application/x-www-form-urlencoded.